# Check parameter string Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have two string types:

First : `key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3...`

Second : `key1=value`

How can I use a Java regular expression to check whether a string is of the first or second type?
Example:

```
String str1 = "a=1&b=2"; // true
String str2 = "a=1&"; // false
String str3 = "a=1"; // true
```

Comment: Are there escape characters you have to take into account?  Can = be part of a value?  Can & be part of a key?

Comment: Clippy says: It looks like you are trying to process GET request parameters. Would you like me to show you the normal ways of doing that rather than rolling your own?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=parse+url+parameters+java

Comment: The temptation is to go for the easy rep points by posting `([^=&]+=[^=&]+&)*[^=&]+=[^=&]+` as an answer, but it's unlikely to be the best thing to do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values are only alphanumeric characters.

```
String text = "a=1&b=2";
boolean match = text.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(&[a-zA-Z0-9]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*");
```